# Controlled Radio Group Button is not showing selected but value gets updated React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The radio group value gets updated but its not showing selected. Over here, the value is shown in console of radio group selected but the radio group is not highlighted or shown selected.

```
   const Quiz = () => {
    const { questions, quiz, options } = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    console.log(currentQuestion[number] + "1q");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const classes = useStyles();
    

    // this is to get the questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetchQuestions(history));
        }
    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
        // Set the new question count based on the current one
        setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
          return Math.min(
            current + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
        });
    };

    const previousQuestion = (current_question) => {
    let new_current_questions = Math.max(current_question - 1, 0);
    setCurrentQuestion(new_current_questions);
  };



function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     
    const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
    console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
    if (!valid) {
        dispatch(postQuiz({ responses: questions, id: quiz.id }, history));
    }
    
    setCurrentQuestion(0);

}
        return (
            !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
                <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={1}>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {/* Only show the question if it's index is less than or equal to the current question */}
   <button type="submit" onClick={previousQuestion}>{current_question+1 ? 'Previous' : null}</button>
                        {questions.map((question, index) => (index <= currentQuestion ? (
                            <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question[question.number]}>
                                <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                                <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value || ''} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                    {options.map((option) => 
                                        <FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                                   )}
                                </RadioGroup>
                            </FormControl>
                        ) : null))}
                        <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                            Submit
                    </Button>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
            )
        );
    };
    
export default Quiz;
```

Though the value of Radio group selected is coming in console.log, but the radio group is not shown selected. How to make it appear which radio button is selected. Please help. Thanks. I want to show the selected radio button also.

Comment: @Aditya: please check

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} checked={question.value===option.score} />
```

Comment: Its not working, value is coming in console. but the selected radio button is not getting highlighting. @Mujeeb Qureshi: thanks for replying.

Comment: One more thing, so the value for `questions` is coming from store, right? In your `handleRadioChange`, is see that you have done this `currentSelection.value = event.target.value;` but I dont see any dispatch to save this value back on the store.

Comment: dispatch is written in handleSubmit to send the value back to store. @Mujeeb Qureshi:

Comment: For sure your issue is with not dispatching the state. RadioGroup's value is binded by `question.value` (`question` here is an object in the `questions` array) So when you click on any Radio button, it updates the object and console logs the value, but the UI is not updated since you have not updated that value in the store. You **have** to set the value in the store in order for a re-rendering to take place and then (and only then) will your Radio button appear as checked or selected

Comment: can you provide the sample code for this? @Mujeeb Qureshi:

Comment: go through this, I scafolded this sandbox using your example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sound-5lo12z?file=/src/Quiz.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out your time to help me. I will once update my code will let you know, if I face any issue. Once again thanks a lot.
One more thing if I remove   <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value}> then everything is fine but i get warning about controlled and uncontrolled value in radio group choose any one of them.  @Mujeeb Qureshi:

Comment: ^exactly, by default the MUI control (or any control for that matter) is uncontrolled. You make it controlled by handling it's value (through state commonly) but in your case the value is coming from the store. 
If you feel you dont want to dispatch and update the store in real time, you can cast the store's questions object in a local state object and then set that! That would do the trick as well

Comment: Thanks then in local statue the issue will fall of page refresh, then I have to store the local state, I will go by dispatch way in that case I will be sure that on page refresh or on re login  the value will remain the same. Thanks a lot. @Mujeeb Quershi:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243730/discussion-between-tanya-maheshwari-and-mujeeb-qureshi).